# In Room db Dao class- how to get values from table by comparing distinct values of a column?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I'm working on Room database, and I want to get two columns values(Category and total amount) from `IncomeExpense` table by comparing distinct values in category column. Let me explain, for example in category column there are 4 rows which have same value(cash), what I want is to calculate total amount of amount column where category is cash and category value (which is cash in this case).
I take these categories values from another table (Category table) in which user can add edit or delete categories.
The problem is that I don't know how to compare category with those values user added in category column which dynamic in this case.

This is my Entity class.

```
@Entity
public class IncomeExpense  {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id =0;

    private String type;
    private int amount;
    private String category;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String mode;
    private String note;
```

This is Dao class where I have to write this query

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(amount), category from IncomeExpense WHERE category like 'What should I write here to get these values in this case'");
```

I just want to get the total amount and category value in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `group by` clause, this will return a list on IncomeExpense but amount will be grouped as per category

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount,category from IncomeExpense GROUP BY category");
public List<IncomeExpense> getCategoryPrice();
```

For Example:
Database Has:
`[ (10, Cash), (50, Cash), (20, Credit), (10, Credit) ]`

The above query will return
`[ (60, Cash), (30, Credit) ]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope this will solve my problem. I'm fairly new in programming
can I make  method as LiveData type like this `LiveData<List<IncomeExpense>> getCategoryPrice();` because in that case I don't have to write the AsyncTask method which is another challenge for me to write that code.

Comment: Yes, you can use `LiveData` for this.  Kindly give upvote and green tick if it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and this gave me the perfect output which I wanted. I gave you the upvote and green tick because you deserve it...Give me upvote if my question is valid...Thank you so much again stay bless